# How to check default SQL DateTime value C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have added a new `DateTime` column to a table. After running the application with a database with existing data, it created the new `DateTime` type column (*not nullable*) successfully using code first migration, Entity Framework and SQL Server.

But the default value for the column is `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`. I couldn't check the same in the code. I tried `DataTime.MinValue`, `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.MinValue.Value` but the values are different and not same.

Is there a standard way to compare the default `DateTime` value across all the databases? **OR** is there a way to configure default value of a `DateTime` type variable while declaring it in the model?

The declaration of the column in the model:

```
public DateTime AddedOn { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to configure a meaningful default in your code.

Comment: @DaleBurrell: please suggest me an optimal way to configure default DateTime

Comment: I would make it nullable as that way you know precisely that you have no value yet. But google entity framework datetime defaults, there are loads of resources out there.

Comment: this can be helpful. You can define your default values. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/A-flexible-Default-Value-11c2db19

Answer (score 0):

One way to compare two datetime values is to use timespan. So, you can use this:

```
TimeSpan span = dateTimeFromDatabase - defaultDateTime;

if (span == TimeSpan.Zero)
// both are same.
```

You might wanna convert datetime from database and default to SqlDateTime and then do the difference to get TimeSpan.